# what is the difference between the regular camera and the first person camera?

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics

I'm asked to implement first person camera but all I know is the regular camera that moves when I hit specific keys and could anyone tell me the steps to implement it?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "regular camera".

Comment: Do you mean the difference between a 3rd person camera and a first person camera? (Or more accurately, 3rd vs 1st person point of view?)

Answer (score 3):

A first-person camera is one that is always situated where a playable character's head/eyes would be, and thus always perceives the world from the perspective that that character would. This is in contrast to a third-person camera, for example, which is typically situated somewhere else in the world and sees a playable character from an external perspective.

Both kinds of camera can be programmed to move when specific keys are hit, so your definition of "regular camera" in this context is somewhat nonsensical.

First-person camera's are, however, typically controlled by having some kind of axis-based device (like a mouse or gamepad stick) yaw the view with X-axis motion and pitch the view with Y-axis motion. Another set of inputs, typically from a keyboard or the *other* gamepad joystick) move the character around the world (and thus, since the camera is tied to the character's head, move the camera as well).

Hopefully that gives you the context you need to implement your camera. Good luck!